# Fedora 27 does not allocate much space for home folder

Tags: linux, hard-drive, fedora, gparted

I have installed Fedora 27 on a new machine, with a Samsung 850 EVO 250 GB.
When migrating my home drive from my old pc (I used Deja dup), it complains that I don't have enough space on my home drive. All of my fiels on my previous PC total to 131 GB.

On the new installation, it says I only have 52.6 GB Total on localhost.localdomain, and 46.6GB available.
[image: Devices and location]

I have installed GParted, but I'm not really sure of how to use it to increase my home partition, or if GParted IS the right tool for me.
[image: gparted]

Can anyone help me to increase my home partition, please? I have been stuck on this for two days. Most of the solutions I have seen, refer to virtual machines.
 I have run the following command:

```
$ sudo  df -h -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs
Filesystem              Size        Used    Avail   Use%    Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root 49G     5.5G    41G     12%     /
/dev/sda1               976M    177M    732M    20%     /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora-home 176G    174M    167G    1%      /home
```

My home folder is:

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/lucas
```

Thanks,
Lucas

Comment: Your root and home filesystems both have plenty of space left. Can you verify what your homedir is by using 'echo $HOME' in a terminal?

Comment: Hi @HoD, I've updated the question. It's also listed on the first screen shot. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df is definitive here.

Apart from the partition mounted as /boot, you have a single primary partition which is an LVM "physical volume" in the "fedora" Volume Group.

The fedora Volume Group has a root "Logical Volume" and a home logical volume, each with a filesystem on it. I expect there may also be a swap logical volume.

You can see the logical volumes with:

`# lvs`

as root, or:

`$ sudo lvs`

For example on my system:

```
LV   VG      Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%...
home fedora  -wi-ao---- <417.90g                                                    
root fedora  -wi-ao----   50.00g                                                    
swap fedora  -wi-ao----   <7.84g
```

In screenshot you posted at the top, the "localhost.localdomain" information is only for the root filesystem and doesn't include the size of /home.

TL;DR
You have around 167G free space in your home directory and don't need to extend it.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. I re installed it again, and I clicked the option where it claimed free spaced, or something like that. The installer I used was anaconda. Thank you!